# radio mics, what is in the future

Tags: microphone, digital, radio, future

what is the future of radio mics, is it worth spending thousands of euros (or dollars) now for devices that soon may become antiquate? are we expecting some total change or improvement in wireless technology? I am refering at a pro range.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question and probably not within the range of what this forum was intended for.

Answer (score 0):

**"Change"?**  Certainly. Governments are re-purposing vast swaths of bandwidth from traditional users (which permitted or tolerated small-beans users like wireless mics) to new users like "land-mobile" (i.e. cell phones and other consumer wireless) which do NOT tolerate "white-space" unofficial users like wireless mics.  Nobody knows exactly where this is going or where it will end up.

**"Improvement"?** That is a different matter. And rather subjective depending on how you are defining "improvement".  Certainly we have much better and cheaper technology with spread-spectrum, frequency-hopping, auto-pairing digital wireless technology (courtesy of WiFi, BlueTooth, et.al.)

While this new digital technology offers all the aforementioned benefits, it also brings with it the disadvantages of latency (which is not an issue with digital communication like WiFi, BlueTooth, or even cell phones).  And the disadvantage of shrinking available RF spectrum (which is the same problem whether analog or digital.)